# $L_2$ integrability of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $g(x,u)\in C^{\infty}([a,b] \times \mathbb{R})$

Suppose $\bar u \in L^{\infty}(a,b)$. Then, the book that I am reading says that
$g(x,\bar u(x)) \in L^2(a,b)$

But, why is that true?

Comment: You can actually say more: $g(\cdot, \bar{u}(\cdot))\in L^\infty(a, b)$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 2):

Let $m=\inf \bar{u}, M=\sup \bar{u}$. Since $g\in L^\infty\left( [a, b]\times [m, M]\right)$, the composed function $g(\cdot, \bar{u}(\cdot))$ is in $L^\infty(a, b)$.

Comment: What would be a direct way to see that the composed function $g$ is in L^2 without showing that it is in $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: @pm021: I cannot imagine anything more direct than this, frankly.